# How to find the nearest value from array?

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

```
public class A6{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String personInfo[][]={ 
                {"Anderson",  "Varejao",     "1125"},
                {"Giorgi",  "Tevzadze",      "1125"},
                {"Will",      "Cherry",      "1225"},
                {"Kevin",     "Love",        "2525"},
                {"Kyrie",     "Livings",      "454"},
                {"Dion",      "Malborg",    "6250" } 
        };

        //max - who has the highest salary
        if(args[0].equals("max")){
            int max = Integer.parseInt(personInfo[0][2]);

            for(int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {
                int l = Integer.parseInt(personInfo[i][2]);        
                if(max < l){
                    max = l;
                }
             }

            for(int i = 0; i < personInfo.length; i++) {
                if(max == Integer.parseInt(personInfo[i][2])){
                     System.out.println(personInfo[i][0]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("His sallary is:" +max );


        //  va ZZZ        - who has the closest salary to value ZZ
        if(args[0].equals("va")){
            for(int iž0; i < personInfo.length; i++{

            int l = Integer.parseInt(personInfo[i][2]);
            ...

        }
    }
}
```

I already wrote a method that finds person with a highest salary and now I am trying to found who has the closest salary to my entered value. For example: I enter into command line java A6 456 and should get answer from a command line Kyrie Livings. I have started doing this by writing a for loop and converting String values to int from personInfo. Any advices?

Comment: are there any memory constraints?

Comment: you could create a loop which iterates over all and calc the "distance"  and search for the min value

Comment: You can do the same thing as `max` but instead of checking for max, check for `min abs(diff)`. That's the minimum absolute value for the difference between the number entered and the salary.

Comment: My advices: 1. indent your code properly. Not just for us, but for you. Reading your own code and debugging it is way easier when it's properly formatted. 2. Use a class Person, with named properties, using the appropriate types, to represent a person. Not an array of Strings. `person.getSalary()` is way simpler than `Integer.parseInt(person[2])`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: (considering there are no constraints on memory usage):

```
int index = 0, minDiff = 0, diff = 0;

for(int i = 0;i<personInfo.length;i++){
    diff = Math.abs(personInfo[i][2] - inputVal);
    if(diff<minDiff){
        minDiff = diff;
        index = i;
    }        

}
return personInfo[index][2];
```

`inputVal` is the parameter you will pass to this function for which you want to find the nearest salary. You can modify this logic to accommodate your needs for this use case.

Comment: Please fix issue with `diff` variable.